# What's wrong with this SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It's SQL Server:

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    Tb_Supplier.State, Tb_Supplier.City,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Tb_Supplier.Name) as Suppliers
    Tb_Consumer.State, Tb_Consumer.City,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Tb_Consumer.Name) as Consumers
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Why are you using an inefficient cross join (cartesian product) instead of an inner join? What error is returned?

Comment: inner join wouldn't work here because he needs counts from both (and in some cases it may be zero.  but a full outer join may work if supported by RDBMS being used.  I'm not sure what the desired output should look like.  it could just be, State, city, supplier_count, Consumer_count.

Comment: You have multiplied the rows in a Cartesian product. That is wrong. You need 2 group by queries, one for suppliers, one for consumers,  then a full outer join between them using state and city to join by (assuming your dbms supports that join type)

Comment: @Used_By_Already can you show it please?

Comment: I have tagged the question `sql-server` and `tsql` (I assume "msql" is "mssql") PLEASE use such tags in future questions

Comment: @dedpo: "MSQL" is very unclear - did you mean to write "MySQL" and just forgot the "y" ? Do you mean Microsoft SQL Server? Please use the official product names (MySQL, SQL Server) for clarity - and not made up abbreviations - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
      COALESCE(s.state, c.state) AS state
    , COALESCE(s.city, c.city) AS city
    , COALESCE(s.Suppliers, 0) AS Suppliers
    , COALESCE(c.Consumers, 0) AS Consumers
FROM (
      SELECT
            Tb_Supplier.State
          , Tb_Supplier.City
          , COUNT(Tb_Supplier.Name) AS Suppliers
      FROM Tb_Supplier
      GROUP BY
            Tb_Supplier.City
          , Tb_Supplier.State
) AS s
      FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  Tb_Consumer.State
                , Tb_Consumer.City
                , COUNT(Tb_Consumer.Name) AS Consumers
            FROM Tb_Consumer
            GROUP BY
                  Tb_Consumer.City
                , Tb_Consumer.State
      ) AS c ON s.state = c.state
                  AND s.city = c.city
```

The query above uses what I assume are "master tables" for Suppliers and Consumers, so rows in each should unique define a Supplier or Consumer. Hence `count(distinct...)` is not required in the above approach. A `full outer join` is used because there may be suppliers in state/city with no matching consumers and vice-versa. Due to this `coalesce` is used in the final select clause to deal with possible NULLs coming from either the supplier or consumer side.

**Why you should stop using commas between tables:**

```
-- Accidental Cross Join? (Cartesian Product)
-- or is it Deliberate
select * from table_one, table_two
```

In the above example **each row** of table_one is multiplied **by all the rows** of table_two. So, if both tables had 100 rows, the result is 100*100 = 10,000 rows. Did I want 10,000 rows?

You have no idea if I wanted it or not, it could be deliberate or just an accident.

```
select * from table_one CROSS JOIN table_two
```

But now I DO know that the cross join is deliberate.

Look back at your original question.

```
FROM 
    Tb_Supplier, Tb_Consumer
GROUP BY 
    Tb_Supplier.City, Tb_Supplier.State, Tb_Consumer.City, Tb_Consumer.State​
```

If you had 1,000 Suppliers and 100,000 consumers how many rows did you create in that from clause? (1,000 * 100,000 = 100,000,000) I'm quite certain that was accidental, *and that is why you should stop using commas between tables in the from clause.*

Comment: @dedpo you tried to edit my comment, but that edit has been rejected. What were you trying to do? do you need something?